# Spring Boot 2.1.8 With SAML InResponseToField of the Response doesn't correspond to sent message

Tags: java, single-sign-on, backend, saml

I am trying to implement `SSO` in my `Spring Boot` 2.1.8 with SAML and getting below error.

> store-type: NONE, Spring `HTTP` session enabled
>   **`@EnableSpringHttpSession`**. If I remove **`@EnableSpringHttpSession`** it's working fine but it's not working store-type: `JDBC` and `store-type`: `Redis`

I tried to test with two different domains and both have https only. if anyone have any idea please provide the solution.

**Error log here:**

> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: InResponseToField of the Response
>   doesn't correspond to sent message xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:88)
>     ... 118 more

Comment: could you edit your question? This is not really readable

Comment: Did you check SAML message flow with SAML tracer tool? Is the value for `InResponseTo` in the SAML response sent by the IdP the same as the value of `ID` in SAML AuthnRequest sent by SP?

Comment: Yes. it is verified both id values are same.